# How to get logged in username of Jenkins in parameter's Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins parameter, I'm writing Groovy script and in that script I need to pass Jenkins logged in username NOT user. User and username, could be different

Ex - User, that is displayed left to 'log out', could be - Bob Gill and username, used to login - could be - bob

User can be retrieved using `User.current()`. Please tell me how to get username.

**NOTE** I don't need username in pipeline code. I need it in Groovy script of parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Java API documentation for `hudson.model.User`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html):

> `String`  `getDisplayName()`
>   Returns the user name.
>
> `String`  `getFullName()`
>   Gets the human readable name of this user.
>
> `String`  `getId()`

It's not clear to me from your question what data you want (I think it's the user ID?), so I'm not sure which of these methods will get you that data (`getId()`?).  But in any case, you would call the method like:

```
User.current().getId()
```

Comment: Yes jayhendren, `getId()` is what I needed. Thanks a lot for help and most importantly pointing to documentation link.